Ribbon X Editor - Custom Ribbon In Excel - Icon Visibility Issue When Office Theme is Changed From Colorful To Black
I have created a custom ribbon in Excel using the Ribbon X Editor, where I added a "menu" and a "button" to my ribbon.
Below is how it looks:

However, when I change the Office theme to "Dark", the icon colours in the "menu" do not adjust to remain visible against the dark background:

My icons are transparent with black color borders, and I got them from Icon8.
Here is my Excel file:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oh5TGwgNhVly_z2Qg1zRa8qqOuyqCCpx?usp=sharing
Note: You don't have to allow the macro to view the icon in the ribbon.
Below are my XML code in RibbonXEditor:
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="RibbonLoad">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="RibbonTab" label="Robot">
        <group id="grp." label="Automation">
            <menu id="menu" label="1. Confirm Bank Details With Client" itemSize="large" size="large" image="Conf1" >
               
               <button id="ConfirmData" label="a) Draft Email To Confirm Bank Details" description="In 'Data' sheet, use the visible data to prepare bank details listing and draft email for each client." image="em11" />
               
               <button id="PullReply" label="b) Pull Client Reply In Monitor Folder" description="In 'Monitor - Client Reply' folder, read each Excel and write the client replies to 'Reply' sheet." image="pull22000" />
               
               <button id="UpdateDatabase" label="c) Update Confirmed Details To Database" description="In 'Reply' sheet, push the confirmed details with 'Ready' selected to database." image="Up1" />
             
             </menu>
                 
            <button id="ConfirmData1" size="large" label="1. Draft Email To Confirm Bank Details" image="em11" onAction="RibbonAction"/> 
            
            <separator id="separator1" />
            
            <button id="PullReply1" size="large" label="2. Pull Client Reply In Monitor Folder " image="pull22000" onAction="RibbonAction"/> 
            
            <separator id="separator2" />
            
            <button id="UpdateDatabase1" size="large" label="3. Update Confirmed Details To Database" image="Up1" onAction="RibbonAction"/> 
           
            <separator id="separator22" />
            
            <button id="PrepareConfirmation1" size="large" label="2. Prepare Confirmation + Authorisation Letters" image="Wr1" onAction="RibbonAction"/>
            
            <separator id="separator3" />
            
            <button id="ConfirmationEmail" size="large" label="3. Draft Emails For Client Signatory" image="Em1" onAction="RibbonAction"/>         
        </group>

      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>

How can I change this such that my icon in "menu" to remain visible in "Dark" theme?
As a last resort, I am considering adding a white outline to the icons.
